# How to scroll in horizontal scroll view

Tags: java, android, oracle

I have made a scroll view in my app it works fine. I have some buttons on click of button i want to scroll to desired position. How can i achieve this And one last thing how can i end the spaces between i images in grid view so all the photos sick together.
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
yourScrollView.post(
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            yourScrollView.scrollTo(desiredPositionX, desiredPositionY);
        } 
    }
);
```

Comment: You'll have to show us some code of yours if we're to be able to help you further. :-)